# Try catch block is not catching nested callbacks

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to use try/catch when it comes to nested callbacks. Why doesn't this piece of code catch my new error ?

```js
function test(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    throw new Error("timeout Error");
  }, 2000);
}

try {
  test(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The error happens asynchronously, when the function passed to `setTimeout` runs. By the time the error is thrown, the `test` function has already finished executing.

Comment: @runners3431 https://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/12/31/asynchronous-error-handling-in-javascript/

Comment: There are several ways to do it. You could move the `try`/`catch` block into the function passed to setTimeout, and provide an error callback to the `test` function that you can call from the inner `catch` block.

Comment: so it seems best pratctice is not to use try/catch and throw new Error with async but rather pass in an error parameter and test for that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to set a timer for Javascript execution. Here's one way that uses [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await Promise.race([

      // Timer.
      new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          rej("Timeout error!");
        }, 2000);
      }),

      // Code being timed.
      new Promise((res, rej) => {
        // Do some stuff here.
        // If it takes longer than 2 seconds it will fail.
        res("Finished in under 2 seconds.");
      })

    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("we got an err: " + err);
  }
})();
```